# Sharepoint REST Odata Endpoint filter not Case sensetive

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

i am trying to make rest call with filter some strings. but if strings matched if there case are different.

for eg. filter like below its works if  i pass different case.

```
(username +eq+'username')+and+(password +eq+'pwd')
```

Comment: Do you want to do case insensitive check ?

Comment: @Gaurravs no i want to check with case sensetive